# Is a bridge the only way to work through EnterpriseOne Data Access Drivers from .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, jdbc, jde, enterpriseone

I am working on a project which will eventually require me to work with EnterpriseOne Data Access Drivers.  Straight ODBC drivers are not an option.  My client wishes to leverage the monitoring capabilities of EnterpriseOne's Data Access Driver, ostensibly to spot heavy hitting queries and make the necessary optimisations.

So far, the only viable option has been an ODBC-JDBC bridge, of which there are several vendor-supplied solutions.  However, I'm uneasy with the idea of employing one and would prefer to avoid a .NET -> Java bridging solution if at all possible.  It's another moving part on an integration project that is already "hefty".

I've read that BizTalk has adapters that may be viable, but again, another moving part.  Am I missing a trick?  Is there a way that I can hit the ERP through the EnterpriseOne Data Access Drivers without having to funnel requests over a bridge?   My ideal solution would be some kind of client access driver, but we have to retain the monitoring capabilities that the E1 Data Access Drivers provide.

Answers gratefully appreciated, even if it's "you're definitely stuck with a bridge".